# If statement for translatable product attribute values

Tags: magento-1.9, php, product-attribute, localisation

I'm using this kind of statements on other places in the webshop (product detail page) but I want to use this one is on the category page:

```
<?php if ($_product->getAttributeText('cp_doos_specificaties') == "Ja" || "Yes"): ?>
```

But for some reason this isn't working... When I remove the || `Yes` it's working, but I need the `Yes` **also because the webshop is also in English and otherwise the code won't work**.

Hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Please let me know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo can use like below statement in your case,

This condition is allow both value **Ja** And **Yes**

```
<?php if ($_product->getAttributeText('cp_doos_specificaties') == "Ja" || $_product->getAttributeText('cp_doos_specificaties') == "Yes"): ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Rakesh Jesadiya who is absolutely correct in his answer, I think you should also improve the quality of the IF-statement.

If the attribute `cp_doos_specificaties` is a Yes/No-attribute, it will either have values "0" (for no) or "1" (for yes). Your IF-statement only takes into account 2 languages, and if someone ever adds another, they will have to know this - which is very unlikely to happen.

Instead, better use this:

```
<?php
// language-independent check
if ($_product->getData('cp_doos_specificaties') == "1") {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but I couldn't get it to work the right way :( But thanks for your quick answer!

Comment: It also depends where you call this functions. If you do `Zend_Debug::dump($_product->debug());`, you can see the data available in the place where you are.

Comment: It's working now: `<?php if ($_product->getData('cp_doos_specificaties') == "1"): ?>`

Answer (score 1):

I think Your flat tables is enable so 
Follow below steps,

1. Login to admin panel
2. Goto Catalog > attributes > Manage Attributes
3. Find `cp_doos_specificaties` in attribute code
4. Click on the attribute
5. Set `yes` to `Used in Product Listing`
6. Click on save
7. Do re-indexing from `System->index Managment`
8. Finally clear the cache

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your attribute type, you can use `$_product->getAttributeText('xyz')` or `$_product->getData('xyz')` to get attribute value.

Instead of

```
<?php
if ($_product->getAttributeText('cp_doos_specificaties') == "Ja"
 || $_product->getAttributeText('cp_doos_specificaties') == "Yes"):
?>
```

you should consider to make this work language independend. It seems better to compare the attributes to the **translated value**.

```
if ($_product->getAttributeText('cp_doos_specificaties') == $this->__('Yes'))
```

*Now make shure "Yes" is somewhere translated in one of your `translation.csv`.*

If the attribute only returns `0` or `1`, you can use

```
if ($_product->getData('cp_doos_specificaties'))
```