# If Attribute is set to Yes

Tags: magento-1.9, php, attributes

Im trying to get a series of attributes to show if an attribute value is set to yes.

Here is my code but it is not working:

```
 <?php if($_product->getAttributeText("vm_activate")== 1) ?>
        <div class="product-sku"><span><?php echo $this->__('VMware SKU: ') ?></span><?php echo $_product->getVmwareSku() ?></div>
        <div class="product-sku"><span><?php echo $this->__('VMware Type: ') ?></span><?php echo $_product->getVmware() ?></div>
        <div class="product-sku"><span><?php echo $this->__('VMware Price: ') ?></span><?php echo $_product->getVmwarePrice() ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: what is the name you are created attribute?

Comment: It is set to vm_activate

Comment: What type of attribute is it? (Dropdown, text ...)

Comment: Its a Yes/ No dropdown

Comment: Have you tried suggestion from below?

Comment: I did. It did not work. Is your code for a product page or category page?

Comment: Should work with both ... make sure that "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end" and "Used in Product Listing" is set to "yes" in manage attributes admin section. Rerun indexer if you have changed attribute settings.

Comment: What about used for sorting?

Comment: It's just required if it should appear in your toolbar as sorting option.

Comment: I still have the issue with the attribute getVmware pulling in the db table row number instead of the attribute value.

Comment: "After some tinkering this worked" ... and it will break with localisation. Still bet for `getData()` ;)

Comment: What do you mean by localisation?

Comment: I mean when you use your website with multiple languages. Your check only works for "Yes", not not for "Ja" or "Oui". Maybe read this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/174163/46249

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tinkering this worked:

```
<?php if ($_product->getAttributeText('vm_activate') == "Yes"): ?>
    <div class="product-sku"><span><?php echo $this->__('VMware SKU: ') ?></span><?php echo $_product->getVmwareSku() ?></div>
    <div class="product-sku"><span><?php echo $this->__('VMware Type: ') ?></span><?php echo $_product->getVmware() ?></div>
    <div class="product-sku"><span><?php echo $this->__('VMware Price: ') ?></span><?php echo $_product->getVmwarePrice() ?></div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
<?php $attribute = $_product->getAttributeText("vm_activate"); ?> //return true of false, 0 or 1
<?php if($attribute) : ?> // if is true or 1
    <div class="product-sku"><span><?php echo $this->__('VMware SKU: ') ?></span><?php echo $_product->getVmwareSku() ?></div>
    <div class="product-sku"><span><?php echo $this->__('VMware Type: ') ?></span><?php echo $_product->getVmware() ?></div>
    <div class="product-sku"><span><?php echo $this->__('VMware Price: ') ?></span><?php echo $_product->getVmwarePrice() ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This works. However its pulling the db id and not the attribute value. Do I need to call something. additional to the page?

Comment: Normally it should work with `getAttributeTest()`, try this : `  $value = $product->getResource()->getAttribute($attribute_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($product);`

Comment: If it's working for you, please accept the answer

Comment: It does not. The code on the second comment kills the whole thing. Also, I'm trying to hide the whole section id its set to no.

Comment: I don't know but it works for me `getAttributeText("vm_activate")`, try this one `$prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$attribute = $prod->getResource()->getAttribute('vm_activate')->getFrontend()->getValue($prod);
echo $attribute;` otherwise i have no idea.